# Xamarin Live Player Visualization Error: Didn't Find Class

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, onesignal, xamarin-live-player

I've been trying to get the OneSignal Xamarin SDK setup complete to test it out for an app I'm working on, but I've run into a wall after finishing the setup according to the instructions here [OneSignal Documentation - Xamarin SDK Setup](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk-setup). When I go to test the app on the Xamarin Live Player on my phone.

I get a visualization error as follows:

> Didn't find class "com.onesignal.OneSignal" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xamarin.live-n4xLe1XSCWWGOA9DcqcG-g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xamarin.live-n4xLe1XSCWWGOA9DcqcG-g==/lib/arm,/data/app/com.xamarin.live-n4xLe1XSCWWGOA9cqcG-g==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,/system/lib,/vendor/lib]] (ClassNotFoundException)

I'm at a total loss at how to proceed, no where else does this error pop up when I search for other solutions. And to top it off, the code works perfectly on the emulator built into Visual Studio. I can send notifications through the OneSignal website and receive them on the emulator instantly with no issues. But for some reason, it fails every time on my phone with that same error.

Comment: Does it work in the device when you directly deploy to it (i.e. not using Xamarin Live Player)

Comment: @SushiHangover it looks like when I do connect my phone to my pc and run it that way it works fine. I guess I can do that instead of running it on the Xamarin Live app now, thanks! Any ideas why it failed on the app though?

Comment: Live Player does not work for everything, it is mainly designed to be a quick XAML/UI display platform and not a full debugging platform. You should post your issue to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com and then the Microsoft devs can determine if is it something they can/will fix in future release or not.

Answer (score 0):

SushiHangover gave me the solution.